# Why do my water pipes jump when running water?

Tags: plumbing, water

I turn the water on half to full volume and the pipes make a jumping noise about every 4 to 5 seconds.  The do not make any noise when turning the faucet on or off.  If I run the water slow, it doesn't do it, just when I try to get a full stream of water.  What can I do to stop this?

Comment: Does this happen for both the hot and cold, or just one of them?

Answer (score 1):

It could also be that you may have some pockets of air in the pipes that cause them to jump or knock. You can try shutting off you main water valve, then open all of faucets until there is no water left. Then with the faucets and spickets open turn the main valve on.

Answer (score 1):

At hardware store I worked at we sold something called a "hammer arrester" (sp). It was a short piece of copper tube that was closed at one end; like a copper test tube.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just vibration making the pipes wiggle at a certain flow rate where the vibration wavelength oscillates just right to be amplified into actual pipe movement. Wherever you have access, strap down the pipes. If you do not have access, you will need to decide how irritating the noise is compared to the work required to gain access and strap down the pipes.